# No popup in App Store that app is bigger than 100 MB

Tags: ios-appstore

I published an application in the App Store named HIV Clinical Guide. This application is more than 100 MB, so it is not possible to download it on a cellular network. Normally when you press the download icon in the App Store, you get a popup that you can only download the app on Wi-Fi, because Apple doesn't allow you to download an application that is more than 100 MB by 3G/4G.

The problem is that with my application, the download starts (you see the blue square), but is not really downloading (because using cellular). When switching to Wi-Fi, the circle is filled (so the app is downloading).

The question is why the user doesn't get the popup when on cellular? Now it looks like that notting is happening (and that's correct) but now we get a lot of questions why the app is not downloading.

I cannot find anything about this. Everywhere I look the documentation says that you get a popup…

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of iOS are you referring to here?

Comment: I am not referreing to one specific iOS version. It happens on all the iOS versions when downloading cellulary

Comment: Are you sure that it is only your application and not something that is wrong with the device you are trying it on?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is not only happening on my phone only. You can try it yourself when you have an iPhone/iPad ;)

Comment: @GercoBrandwijk I tried downloading your app and I saw the same problem. But I also noticed that I do not get the popup on other apps either. Normally it does come up but now when I tried with an another app over 100MB it didn't. If you try now to download an another app that is over 100MB over cellular, do you get the pop-up?

Comment: When I try it with GarageBand (627 mb) I get the popup. With which app did you try it? But for example MMX Racing is not giving me a popup...

Comment: @GercoBrandwijk I tried with "All Guns Blazing" (some random app that was featured on the AppStore and is over 100MB, it is 260MB).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24762/discussion-between-gerco-brandwijk-and-dempa).

Comment: @GercoBrandwijk I'm moving over to the chat.

Comment: @Dempa Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to join chat.. ;) All Guns Blazing is not giving me a popup either. So it looks like that this problem is with more apps..

Comment: @GercoBrandwijk Then it may be something temporary with the AppStore. Try again tomorrow and see if it has fixed it self.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to download both the Askers application and an another application over 100MB. Neither I nor the Asker did get the pop-up about downloading large apps over cellular.

It looks like it is a temporary issue with the AppStore.
My recommendation is that you try again tomorrow or the day after that and see if the issue have fixed it self. If not, then you can continue further investigation in the issue.